# check what text is after certain text

Tags: javascript

I was wondering because I am making a website and I need to make JavaScript code that checks what text is going aftet certain text, I think I need to give an example, so:

```
A= txt
```

`A=` - the certain text that shows what text to copy, in this case the text that needs to be copied is `txt`

So the problem is: I don't know how to check if there is `A=` in the textarea and then take text as a variable `txt`

```
function formAnswer() {
    var A = document.getElementById('textarea').innerHTML = "A=";
    var ans = document.getElementById('textarea').value;

    var answer = document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = A + 'ans';
}
```

This is what I've done so far, but its probably garbage, not code.

Comment: What do you know? Do you know how to get the  value of a textarea? How to check whether a string contains another string? How to get a substring from a string?

Comment: Can you share some code? Depending on how your data is structured there'll be different ways to get to it that is concise and fault-tolerant.

Comment: I know how to copy a entire textarea content, but I'm not sure how to copy just a part of the content if I can say so. So basically I have no code.

Comment: Use a regular expression to match `A=` followed by something, and get the part after it using a capture group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regular expression.

```
function formAnswer() {
    var input = document.getElementById('textarea').value;
    match = input.match(/A=(.*)/);
    if (match) {
        return match[1];
    }
}
```

`/A=(.*)/` is a regular expression that matches `A=` followed by anything (including an empty string). The capture group `(.*)` will capture everything after `A=`. If the input matches the pattern, `match` will be an array, and `match[1]` contains the part of the input that was captured.

If you want to requre that there be non-empty text after `A=`, change `.*` to `.+`.